# Android. Foreground service always stopped

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

I have an Android application and it has a foreground service. Service consumes data from some api. This process can take minutes and hours. While service is running it writes logs to logcat with progress of its execution and other information. But every time I run my application (and the service) it stops to work after some time. I suppose OS kills it for its reasons but I can not  understadn why and how to avoid it. I looked at logcat and found some suspiciois records:

```
04-16 16:24:41.180 28045 28058 I MyCoolApplication: Background concurrent copying GC freed 90524(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 70(1400KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 7MB/14MB, paused 811us total 109.136ms
04-16 16:24:51.497 28045 28045 I MyCoolApplication: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 87516(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 30(600KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4MB/9MB, paused 303us total 51.352ms
```

And `MyCoolApplication` is my app's name. These records appears while app is running and continue to appear after its death. What could it be and how to fix this problem?

UPD:

Here is my service (c# code, I use Xamarin)

```
class MyApiService : BackgroundService
{
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        var notification = CreateNotification();
        StartForeground(100, notification);            
        ConsumeDataFromApi(); 
        StopSelf(startId);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    private Notification CreateNotification() 
    {
        // some code here 
    }

    private void ConsumeDataFromApi(DateTime start, DateTime end) 
    {
         // some long-running method consuming and performing data from json api
    }
}
```

Comment: This error are related to memory exception. So if you are doing any major image processing or processing large amount of data then its being freed by the GC, at that time you can get Out Of Memory this issue.

Comment: Can you put the code you are using ? Are u loading images ?

Comment: @ismailalaoui No I don't process any images. Code is added